# Can we make a mapping function from "sum operator" to "max operator" or inverse

Tags: logic

Suppose we have a knowledge base $K$ :
$$K=\{(\phi_i, \alpha_i) : i=1..n\}$$
Such as:

- $\phi_i$ : are propositional formulas (CNF format for example).
- $\alpha_i$ : are integers ($\alpha_i \in \mathcal{N})$.

And we have two functions $S$ and $M$, such as for each logical interpretation $\omega$ :

- $M(\omega)= max\{\alpha_i : (\phi_i, \alpha_i) \in K, \omega \not\vDash  \phi\}$
- $S(\omega)= \sum\{\alpha_i : (\phi_i, \alpha_i) \in K, \omega \not\vDash  \phi\}$

Can we define a function $F$ such that, for each logical interpretation $\omega$:
$$M(\omega)=F(S(\omega))$$
or
$$S(\omega)=F(M(\omega))$$

Can a such function exists? else, can we proof its nonexistence?

---

**Example:**
let $K=\{(a \lor b, 6), (\lnot{a} \lor c, 4), (c, 3), (a, 1), (\lnot{b},1))\}$ a knowledge base, consider the interpretation $ab\lnot{c}$, we have :

- $M(ab\lnot{c})=4$
- $S(ab\lnot{c})=4+3+1=8$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$S(\omega)=F(M(\omega))$ is not possible, consider $\{(a, 1), (b, 1), (b \vee c, 1)\}$. Then $M(\lnot a \lnot bc) = M(\lnot abc) = 1$, but $S(\lnot a \lnot bc)  \neq S(\lnot abc)$, and $F(1)$ can't possibly equal both values.

Can you provide a similar counterexample for $M(\omega)=F(S(\omega))$?

Comment: Thank you for your response!, yes, a similar counter example for $M(\omega)=F(S(\omega))$ is as follow : consider $K=\{  (a \lor b, 4), (a,5), (\lnot{c},9) \}$. Then we have : $S(\lnot{a}\lnot{b}\lnot{c})=S(a\lnot{b}c)=9$, and $M(\lnot{a}\lnot{b}\lnot{c})\ne M(a\lnot{b}c) (5 \ne 9)$, but are those two counter examples are sufficient to prove the non-existence of $F$, can't we exploit the definition of $M$ and $S$?

Comment: @youneszeboudj Yes, that is sufficient to show $F$ can't exist, at least not for arbitrary $\omega$. If $F$ exists it must be a function, and a function can't map the same input to multiple different outputs.

Comment: orlp right, thanks again